# Modify an element of a matrix

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

Im trying this but doesn't seem to work:

```
A  = {{1,2},{3,4}}
A[[1]][[2]] = 5;
```

How could I do that?

Currently I'm doing

```
list = {3,5};
A[[2]] = list;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right, except for a minuscule error :)

You wrote:

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}   A[[1]][[2]] = 5; 
                     ^
                     ^
                     |
               This space means
                multiplication!
```

The correct code is

```
A = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} ;  A[[1]][[2]] = 5;
```

Usually written as:

```
    a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}} ;  
    a[[1, 2]] = 5;
```

Remember to start your identifiers with lowercase letters, as capitals are reserved for system's names

Comment: The question didn't actually have a space — it had a line break. SO put it on the same line because it was not wrapped in a code block. So what he originally had should've worked. I'm guessing this is what happened: Since the first line was not terminated, it printed the original contents of A to the notebook. OP took that to mean A has not been updated. If they had evaluated `A` again, they would've noticed the change. Either way, TL :)

Comment: a[[1]][[2]] = 5; doesn't work for me (Set::setps: A〚1〛 in assignment of part is not a symbol.), but a[[1,2]] = 5; works fine, thanks for the answer.